# regex url param for Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

i'am trying to take url param with Regex for the Google Analytics Tracking.

This is the URL

https://www.mus.at/firma-privat/berechnen?itemid=c12db9ac-efe0-421b-8a86-4b2ae84ef592&step=MeineVorberechnung#ms

I dont have any experience with regex. Can someone help me to take only this part of the link "=MeineVorberechnung#ms"

Thank you very much!

Best,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Just to use this string to get all URLs with that substring:

```
=MeineVorberechnung#ms
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Michele! I need it for the Google Analytics funnel. Should i write directly =MeineVorberechnung#ms or \/=MeineVorberechnung#ms

Comment: Slash is not in that part of the URL, so you have to not use that. Check if in GA there is the #ms at the end of the URL.

Comment: Should i use in GA Goals the whole domain mus.at/=MeineVorberechnung or i should place only this part of the expression =MeineVorberechnung ? I'm talking about destination, the Goal.